# substitute elements in the nested list by their counting numbers

Tags: python

I have a nested list:

```
x=[[[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2]], [[0, 1], [0, 1, 2]], [[0]], [[0, 1], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]]
```

Now, the goal is to get a nested list *with the same structure* but with elements replaced by their "global" counting numbers. So, the desired output should look like this:

```
y=[[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5]], [[6, 7], [8, 9, 10]], [[11]], [[12, 13], [14, 15, 16, 17, 18]]]
```

I fight with it for the last couple of hours but without success.

Ideally, I'd like to have a universal solution being able to work with an arbitrary depth of nesting.

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: What have you tried so far, show us some code.

Comment: @plocks I'd like to have it in a compact form of a list comprehension, so I tried this. But now I think this is a bad idea since there should be an ascending count variable somewhere...

Comment: maybe recursion

Comment: @user7647857 maybe check with pandas . if you accpet pandas' solution , I can provide

Comment: Would `[0, 1, 2], [5, 4, 3]` expect to output as: `[0, 1, 2], [8, 7, 6]`? As in each array has the current global count plus the number in each array element: `[5+3, 4+3, 3+3]` where `3` would be the current global count.

Comment: @timgeb I'd be happy to have it done for 2-levels nesting. Arbitrary depth is, as mentioned, an ideal case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a recursive solution that does the replacement in-place and relies on the `type` of the element being replaced. The idea is to keep track of the "global counter" and pass it into the recursive calls so that it knows what to replace elements with:

```
x = [[[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2]], [[0, 1], [0, 1, 2]], [[0]], [[0, 1], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]]

def replace(lst, i):
    for j in range(len(lst)):
        if isinstance(lst[j], list):
            lst[j], i = replace(lst[j], i)
        else:
            lst[j] = i
        i += 1
    return lst, i - 1

replace(x, 0)
print(x)
# [[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5]], [[6, 7], [8, 9, 10]], [[11]], [[12, 13], [14, 15, 16, 17, 18]]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another recursive solution. It uses [`itertools.count`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) and builds a new list. Personally, I like to avoid integer indexing when possible for readability.

```
from itertools import count

def structured_enumerate(lst, counter=None):
    'enumerate elements in nested list, preserve structure'
    result = []
    if counter is None:
        counter = count()

    for x in lst:
        if isinstance(x, list):
            result.append(structured_enumerate(x, counter))
        else:
            result.append(next(counter))
    return result
```

Demo:

```
>>> x = [[[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2]], [[0, 1], [0, 1, 2]], [[0]], [[0, 1], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]]
>>> structured_enumerate(x)
[[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5]],
 [[6, 7], [8, 9, 10]],
 [[11]],
 [[12, 13], [14, 15, 16, 17, 18]]]
```

**~edit~**

Here's an attempt at a generic solution that works with *any* iterable, indexable or not, where you can specifiy iterable types to exclude from iteration.

```
from itertools import count

def structured_enumerate(iterable, dontiter=(str,), counter=None):
    'enumerate elements in nested iterable, preserve structure'
    result = []
    if counter is None:
        counter = count()

    for x in iterable:
        # check if x should be iterated
        try:
            iter(x)
            is_iterable = True
        except TypeError:
            is_iterable = False

        # strings of length zero and one are a special case
        if isinstance(x, str) and len(x) < 2:
            is_iterable = False

        if is_iterable and not isinstance(x, dontiter):
            subresult = structured_enumerate(x, dontiter, counter)
            result.append(subresult)
        else:
            result.append(next(counter))

    return result
```

Demo:

```
>>> fuzzy = [{0, 0}, '000', [0, [0, 0]], (0,0), 0]
>>> structured_enumerate(fuzzy)
[[0, 1], 2, [3, [4, 5]], [6, 7], 8]
>>> structured_enumerate(fuzzy, dontiter=())
[[0, 1], [2, 3, 4], [5, [6, 7]], [8, 9], 10]
>>> structured_enumerate(fuzzy, dontiter=(tuple, set))
[0, [1, 2, 3], [4, [5, 6]], 7, 8]
```